# add tls/ssl for postfix with multiple domains and multiples ips

Tags: postfix

I am working on a postfix server. This server is sending mail through multiple IPs for multiple domains. Some domains have a dedicated IP address. Other are on the same IP.

Everything works fine.

Now, i want to enable SSL and TLS. I know what to do for a postfix server which has a single IP address and a single domain:

```
cd /etc/postfix
openssl req -nodes -new -x509 -keyout dsfc.key -out dsfc.crt
```

Then i have to add this in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/dsfc.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/dsfc.crt
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_req_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_ccert_verifydepth = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/lib/postfix/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 86400
```

But i am not sure it will work in my case. Should i have one certificate per domain or per ip ? Or one certificate will do the job for all the domains ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The SSL/TLS cert and key are for the mail servers domain/IP which all other domains go through so the secure mail server covers all domains that use it, dedicated IPs are of no consequence. For best results and maximum security use the configuration options that are available to you.
If you plan on using smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt realize some mail servers will not accept connection because they do not accept TLS only connections. If you insist on encrypt check your mail log and see if there are any hosts rejecting for this reason. You can create /etc/postfix/tls_policy and add the hosts there and designate may so mail will be delivered IE:

```
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
```

In that file you can add hosts like below

```
live.co.uk             may
live.com               may
charter.net            may
mx.west.cox.net        may
bigpond.com            may
cox.net                may
```

Yes live.com will reject if TLS is forced
Dont forget to run postmap after edits to file

Example:

```
# TLS parameters
# ---------------------------------

# The default snakeoil certificate. Comment if using a purchased
# SSL certificate.
#smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/postfix.pem
#smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem

# Uncomment if using a custom SSL certificate.
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/path/to/ssl/example.com/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/path/to/ssl/example.com/key.pem

# The snakeoil self-signed certificate has no need for a CA file. But
# if you are using your own SSL certificate, then you probably have
# a CA certificate bundle from your provider. The path to that goes here.
smtp_tls_CAfile=/path/to/ssl/example.com/chain.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile=/path/to/ssl/example.com/chain.pem

# trusted CA path, where your server has the trust store of commercial certs
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs

smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
#enable ECDH
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = strong
#enabled SSL protocols, don't allow SSLv2 and SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols= !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols= !SSLv2, !SSLv3
#allowed ciphers for smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
#allowed ciphers for smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
#enforce the server cipher preference
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
#disable following ciphers for smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, MD5 , DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL
#disable following ciphers for smtpd_tls_security_level=may
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, eNULL, EXPORT, DES, RC4, MD5, PSK, aECDH, EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA, EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA, KRB5-DES, CBC3-SHA
#enable TLS logging to see the ciphers for inbound connections
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
#enable TLS logging to see the ciphers for outbound connections
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem

# Note that forcing use of TLS is going to cause breakage - most mail servers
# don't offer it and so delivery will fail, both incoming and outgoing. This is
# unfortunate given what various governmental agencies are up to these days.
#

# For MTAs that reject based on encrypt TLS setting, lets do 'may' to get the mail delivered
#smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy

# AUTH only must be enabled when using smtpd encrypt
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
# Enable and force all incoming smtpd connections to use TLS.
#smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
# Enable and force all outgoing smtp connections to use TLS.
#smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
# Enable (but don't force all incoming smtpd connections to use TLS.
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
# Enable (but don't force) all outgoing smtp connections to use TLS.
smtp_tls_security_level = may

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
```

Comment: In fact what i want to do is to send mails with TLS if remote server accepts TLS and if not send mail in classical way. But i do not know all destination domains.... Thanks

Comment: Bob if thats the case use 'may' instead of 'encrypt' no need to know remote domains postfix will handle that. [Read Postfix TLS](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html). Using encrypt on a public mail server is not a wise decision if you want mail flowing without TLS issues.